# Philosophy as recreation?

Tags: thought-experiment

What do you think about recreational philosophy. Is it different from academic philosophy or professional philosophy?

Or can anyone (or anywhere even) formulate philosophical statements?

Comment: Can we even formulate philosophical statements? The short answer is "yes". The questions keep coming back, they will not stay "analyzed" and put to sleep. Philosophy always starts up again in earnest when we can't hide anymore. We find ourselves shoved into a corner of our own making. There are no hiding places left, then it starts up again. This is my opinion anyway.

Comment: I think you have asked a very good and sophisticated question.  At the end of the day, the answer is with the general public. Do they want something above reductionism and specialization, or do they not. If the public feels a need for it, it will develop, whether inside the philosophy departments or outside of them.

Comment: Quine had a notion of "recreational mathematics" (not employed even indirectly in sciences). [Colyvan](https://books.google.com/books?id=C4jEBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=%22recreational+philosophy%22&source=bl&ots=tTrKY-BKY-&sig=P88gWRb9jxAyl71syWvJe7TkBp4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLsKrOv4fXAhWnsFQKHZ2HB8kQ6AEIQTAF#v=onepage&q=%22recreational%20philosophy%22&f=false) suggested extending that to philosophy, and concluded that most of philosophy is "recreational". Many found it offensive and ironic: this conclusion itself can be taken "recreationally".

Comment: The problem here is not philosophy but the interpretation of "recreational". If it's related to not earning money, the best ancient philosophers did it for free. If it's related to academic grades, the same guys had few, or grades that can be poorly valued under the current standards.

Comment: @Rodolfo - Perhaps you could re-write that leaving out the word 'ancient'.